# Непонятная ошибка компилятора

Tags: c++, компилятор

```
#include <iostream> // Библиотеки
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() //Главный код
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //Рандом
    int RandNum = rand()% 10 + 1;
    try = 0;
    int a;
    cout << "\t Welcome)"<< endl << endl;
    do{ // Цикл
        cout << "Enter a number: "
        cin >> a;
        ++try;
        if(a < RandNum){
            cout << "To low: ";
        }
        else if(a > RandNum){
            cout << "To High: ";
        }
        else
            cout << "You got it in " << try << "try"
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

выдает ошибку у int try = 0 // Требует зачем-то }

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int RandNum = rand()% 10 + 1;
    int a = 0;
    int a;
    cout << "\t Welcome)"<< endl << endl;
    do{
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> a;
        ++a;
        if(a < RandNum){
            cout << "To low: ";
        }
        else if(a > RandNum){
            cout << "To High: ";
        }
        else{
            cout << "You got it in " << a << "try"
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

Comment: `int` пропустили.

Comment: неплохо бы добавить тэг языка на котором это написано.

Comment: Желательно добавлять полный текст ошибки компилятора, а не ее вольный пересказ.

Answer (score 10):

http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

`try` - ключевое слово C++, его нельзя использовать в качестве идентификатора.

Comment: ...а даже если бы `try` не было ключевым словом, у него нет объявления. Это так, дополнение к сведению ТСа.

Comment: Да спасибо, я написал и сразу разобрался